# Binding Field from List of object to a Dropdownlist MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist, dropdownlistfor

I have a list of a certain object, each object contains fields. I need to do a DropDownListFor or DropDownList for that field within that object but its not binding

I initially tried this with a List and this works fine for binding to a normal object field. I then tried converting to SelectList() by doing

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.MyListOfObjects[i].FieldName, new SelectList(Model.MySelectList, "Value", "Text"))
```

I then tried to set the "Selected" property on the SelectListItem I needed to be selected but still no luck

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyListOfObjects.Count; i++){
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.MyListOfObjects[i].FieldName, Model.MySelectList)
}
```

Model.MySelectList is `List<SelectListItem>`

```
public List<MyCustomObject> MyListOfObjects {get;set;} //populated

public class MyCustomObject{
     public string FieldName {get;set;}
}
```

So in the end, I need the value of `Model.MyListOfObjects[i].FieldName` tp be selected from the `Model.MySelectList()`. The value in the select list does match so I cant see whats wrong

Thank you. Appreciate any help

EDIT: I know I can use "EditorFor" templates for the object used in `Model.MyListOfObjects` but I would prefer to avoid it if possible as I am using that object with other things so if I need another version of the object in editorfor then I wouldnt be able to do it. As a last resort though, I will just have to change the object to a unique one and go down the editorfor route

Comment: What is the type of `Model.MySelectList`? Can you please share the code of that?

Comment: It is List<SelectListItem>

Comment: Sorry it was in my answer but wasnt formatted properly so didnt show up. My fault. Edited correctly now :)

Answer (score 0):

`selectListItem` contains `text` and `value`. 
You need to bind `value` field to dropdown not `text` field.

i.e. `model => Model.MyListOfObjects[i].FieldValue`

Check This will help you

Comment: The FieldName contains the value though. Sorry I am not following. The FieldName is just the object fieldname and is populated with a value

Comment: Model.MySelectList is the SelectList parameter which contains the text and value fields that the first parameter bind to